# Want title on TOP from Oracle query

Tags: asp.net, oracle

With the below query I generate a `datable` whose diagram is as below:-

```
SELECT   *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no,
                      CASE
                         WHEN sv.audit_flag = 'N'
                            THEN 'REJECTED'
                         ELSE 'PENDING APPROVAL'
                      END isnullcheck,
                         TO_CHAR (date_in,
                                  'dd-MM-yyyy'
                                 )
                      || ' & '
                      || time_in vehicleindate_time,
                         TO_CHAR (date_out,
                                  'dd-MM-yyyy'
                                 )
                      || ' & '
                      || time_out vehicleoutdate_time,
                      gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno,
                      remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in,
                      CASE
                         WHEN sv.audit_flag = 'N'
                            THEN 'Y'
                         ELSE 'N'
                      END hod
                 FROM xxcus.xxgid_audit_entry sv
                WHERE sv.project_id = '1365'
                  AND (sv.audit_flag IS NULL OR sv.audit_flag = 'N')
      UNION
      SELECT NULL, NULL, 'PENDING APPROVAL', NULL, 'PENDING APPROVAL',
             NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT NULL, NULL, 'REJECTED', NULL, 'REJECTED', NULL, NULL, NULL,
             NULL, NULL
        FROM DUAL) qq
```

ORDER BY isnullcheck DESC

the generated `datable` is as below
[![Datatable][1]][1]

Now what, I want is.
The query will fetch result into two headings
ie. 1. **REJECTED** or 2. **PENDING APPROVAL**
 but what happening here is it is going other than both the heading also. It should not go.

[![Image][2]][2]

Also see the html of grid

How to make that under two headings ?? is there any issue with query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by something else as well, and used NULLS FIRST on that:

```
ORDER BY isnullcheck DESC, mkey NULLS FIRST
```

Comment: let me check and confirm

Comment: superb,It's working now. what was the cause of not working ??

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: i mean to say, for me it was something coming as expected and sometimes not..WHY was that happening ?

Comment: Since there are many rows with the same ISNULLCHECK value, if you don't order by something else as well then the display order of rows with the same ISNULLCHECK value is **arbitrary** and can change from run to run.